# How to execute promise of super class in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise, es6-class, es6-modules

I've a promise in Parent class, whenever I call the promise from child class, it is returning the undefined, instead of executing the promise and returning the resul.

import {newsApiKey as APIKEY, newUrl as APIURL} from "./secretToken";

```
class News{

 constructor(){
    this.token = APIKEY;
    this.url = APIURL;
    this.source = 'bbc-news&';

 }

 topNews(){
   const bbcNews = fetch(`${this.url}?source=${this.source}&sortBy=top&apiKey=${this.token}`);
   bbcNews.then(response => {
     if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
    return response.json()
   })
   .then(json => {
     console.log(json.articles);
     return json.articles;
   })
   .catch((err) => {
      return err.message;
    });
 }  
}


export { News as default};
```

**CHILD CLASS**

```
import News from "./news";

class StickyNote extends News{

    displayNews(){
      let bbcNews = super.topNews(); // It is  returning only undefined
      if (typeof bbcNews != 'undefined') {
        console.log(bbcNews); //
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you call `topNew` from a child class or from outside, it just *doesn't `return` anything*. So why would you expect it to do that?

Comment: If at all, your asynchronous `topNews` method could return a promise, not the result itself immediately. Your `displayNews` method will need to wait for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`topNews` never returns anything, so the result of calling it is `undefined`.

You probably wanted a `return` here:

```
topNews() {
    const bbcNews = fetch(`${this.url}?source=${this.source}&sortBy=top&apiKey=${this.token}`);
    return bbcNews.then(response => {
//  ^^^^^^
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json.articles);
        return json.articles;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err.message;
      });
}
```

Also note that `displayNews` will need to *use* the promise it receives:

```
displayNews(){
  super.topNews().then(articles => {
    // ...use articles
  });
}
```

*(Normally you'd also have a `catch` there at the endpoint of consumption, but as you've converted rejections into resolutions...)*

---

Note: That code has a bit of an anti-pattern in it: It converts a rejection into a resolution with an error message. Anything *using* the promise will never see a rejection, only resolutions with varying return types (whatever `json.articles` is or a string). In general, it's better to allow rejections to propagate, and handle them at the ultimate point of consumption of the entire chain (`displayNews`, I believe, in your example). You might transform their content, but not convert them from a rejection into a resolution.

FWIW, I'd probably rewrite that like so:

```
topNews() {
  return fetch(`${this.url}?source=${this.source}&sortBy=top&apiKey=${this.token}`)
    .catch(_ => {
      throw new Error("network error");
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {                  // "data", not "json" -- it's not JSON anymore
      return data.articles;
    });
}
```

...which ensures that the caller either gets a resolution with the articles, or a rejection with an `Error`, so:

```
displayNews(){
  super.topNews()
    .then(articles => {
      // ...use articles
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // ...show error
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, and the primary problem is that the class is untyped. The problem would be clearly indicated if it were `topNews(): Promise<any[]>`.

Comment: @estus: Whether to use TypeScript or not is off-topic here. Some people love it. Other people hate it. The OP isn't using it, so...

Comment: Indeed, it has no typescript tag, I just saw Angular with modular ES6 and considered it TS, since those two come in pairs.

Comment: @estus: Plenty of people using Angular who aren't using TypeScript. Clearly the OP isn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot for brief details, I really appreciate it.